# Incorporating the self resonance of an LC filter

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

I've been looking at lumped-element on-chip LC filters, like the one discussed in the paper [Circuit Quantum Electrodynamics Architecture for Gate-Defined Quantum Dots in Silicon](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.05571) by Mi et al. from 2017 (published version [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4974536)).

The details are not all that relevant for my question, but to summarize they have DC bias lines that come into close proximity with GHz-scale resonators and they want to avoid leakage into the environment through these DC lines. So they construct a low-pass filter that makes the DC line a very poor path to decay into for the resonator.

They construct the following filter, shown in panel a:
[image]
It consists of a square-type planar spiral inductor, and an interdigital capacitor. Noteworthy also is that the material is thin film superconductor.

Now, in the paper they show the $\vert S_{21}(\omega)\vert^2$ for an inductance of $L_f = 13$ nH and $C_f = 1$pF. They compute this via an ABCD matrix approach, shown by the black line in panel b. The red line is what they measure, the green line denotes the frequency of their resonator, we can ignore these for this question.

Now, my question is as follows. In constructing an inductor in the way that they did, don't you also get self-capacitance? And does that not lead to a self-resonance of the inductor segment? If so, how would one go about incorporating that into the ABCD formalism?

To get started, I reproduced their (very simple, of course) equation as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & i\omega L \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
i\omega C_f & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

One can then use 
\begin{equation}
S_{21} = \frac{2}{A+B/Z_0+CZ_0 +D}
\end{equation}

Plugging in $Z_0 = 50 \Omega$ one reproduces the curve from the paper. I then naively thought that the self-capacitance would enter as a series capacitance in the ABCD formalism. But if I do that, I end up with a system that does not pass DC (which makes sense, of course). And looking at the paper (and their application), that cannot be correct.

So hence my question; how would I go about introducing the effect of the self-capacitance and the resulting self-resonance of the inductor, in this formalism?

Comment: I don't have time for an exhaustive answer, but don't reinvent the wheel! All those structures have been studied in microwave engineering for many years, and there is a wealth of literature on the effect of stray capacitance and other parasitic effects like the proximity effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny to see the classic LC filter from Xiao Mi's work. The LC filter indeed has some parasitic self resonances as you mentioned. To try and model it, you'd need to include a capacitance that shunts the inductor (i.e. in parallel to the inductor). That circuit element will resonate at some frequency $f = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC_p}}$ where $C_p$ is the parasitic capacitance. The matrix for a series impedance is given by:

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & Z(\omega) \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$$

So insert $Z(\omega) = Z_L || Z_{C_p}$ and you should get some self resonance effect. This should go in place of the matrix that contains only the impedance of the inductor. I personally believe the ripple phenomena is more likely to be caused by cabling impedance mismatches and/or slotline modes but that isn't what you asked about.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes a lot of sense. I tried plugging in the impedance of a parallel LC circuit (given by $Z = \frac{-j \omega L}{\omega^2 L C - 1}$) and the result is interesting. You get a resonance where you would expect it, and the filter behaviour is relatively similar up to the resonance frequency, but a lot worse after. So one better minimize that self-capacitance (or make sure you have a lot of inductance).

Comment: Also I agree, the ripples originate from something else. They hypothesized (similar to what you wrote) reflections at the bond wires and parasitic modes due to discontinuities in the ground plane.

Comment: Glad it helps. I work on the same types of circuits more-or-less so this is pretty old hat for me.